# Rename file based on folder parent name

Tags: batch-file, scripting, rename, dos

I'm looking for a batch-script which transforms a file named "template.book" into the name of the folder it is in. For example if the file is in the folder "instruction" I want the batch-file to rename the .book file in instruction.book.

I've tried many solutions which you gave but none of them seem to work for me. Hope you guys can help me out.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF 
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
  'dir /b /s /a-d "%sourcedir%\template.book" '
 ) DO (
  FOR %%b IN ("%%~dpa.") DO ECHO(REN "%%a" "%%~nb.book"
)

GOTO :EOF
```

The required REN commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(REN` to `REN` to actually rename the files.

You would need to set your directory as `sourcedir`. I set my testing directory.

Comment: Hi, it is working. Thanks! I've changed U:\sourcedir to %cd% to make the .bat file usable for multiple folders without having to adjust it.